# Close form without reloading page when sending post request to backend API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

This is probably a simple one, but I have a React front end and Express back end, and I'm sending data to my API through a form on the front end. I have two buttons, one Submit and one Close. The Close button has a click event handler that closes the overlay without leaving the page. I would like my Submit button to work the same using the onSubmit handler. However, even though my post requests goes through successfully, it never closes the overlay despite using the same function.

I can make the app work by using a res.redirect on my back end to the home page, but I'd ideally like to not have the page reload. Additionally, when I have my back end send any kind of data back using res.send() or res.json(), it loads the JSON data in my browser instead of processing it in my front end (e.g. showing all posts in my Posts.js component).

Relevant code:

**Post route**

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

  Post.create(req.body)
    .then(newPost => {
        console.log("Success!")
        res.status(201).json(newPost);
        //res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
    })
})
```

**Form and Close overlay function**

```
handleClose(e) {
    this.props.closeForm();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const postForm =
    <div className="form-popup" id="newPost">
      <form action="http://localhost:5000/api/posts" method="post" className="form-container">

        <h1>New Blog Post</h1>
        <div className="formArea formtitle">
          <label htmlFor="title"><b>Title</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Blog Post Title" name="title" required />

        </div>
        <div className="formArea formlocation">
          <label htmlFor="location"><b>Location</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location" required />
        </div>
        <div className="formArea postcontent">
          <textarea placeholder="Your post here" name="bodyText" required />
        </div>
        <div className="formArea formsubmit">
          <button type="submit" className="btn" onSubmit={this.handleClose} >Post</button>
          <button type="submit" className="btn cancel" onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Two options

- **Recommended:** Send the request by JavaScript using an **[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) call**
- **Hacky solution**: Insert an [iframe tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) in your page and have the `form` have it as a target

## XHR

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '/server', true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
}
xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
```

## iframe

```
<iframe name="formTarget" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form action="http://localhost:5000/api/posts" method="post" target="formTarget">
    <!--Your inputs and other form contents-->        
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with Node.js. Read about [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

To do it the react way, change your code to the following:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    class YourComponent extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                title: '',
                location: '',
                bodyText: ''
            };

            handleOnInputChange = (event)=> {
                const target = event.target;
                const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
                const name = target.name;

                this.setState({
                  [name]: value
                });
            }

            handleSubmitForm = ()=> {
                const { title, location, bodyText } = this.state;

                axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/posts', {
                    userName: name,
                    userLocation: location,
                    text: bodyText
                })
                .then(response=> {
                    //Do something with the response
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(error=>{
                    //Do something with the error
                    console.log(error)
                })
            }
        }

        render(){
            <div className="form-popup" id="newPost">
             <form className="form-container">

               <h1>New Blog Post</h1>
               <div className="formArea formtitle">
                 <label htmlFor="title"><b>Title</b></label>
                 <input type="text" placeholder="Blog Post Title" name="title" required value={this.state.title} onChange={event => this.handleOnInputChange(event)} />

               </div>
               <div className="formArea formlocation">
                 <label htmlFor="location"><b>Location</b></label>
                 <input type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location" required value={this.state.location} onChange={event => this.handleOnInputChange(event} />
               </div>
               <div className="formArea postcontent">
                 <textarea placeholder="Your post here" name="bodyText" required onChange={event => this.handleOnInputChange(event}>{this.state.bodyText}</textarea>
               </div>
               <div className="formArea formsubmit">
                 <button type="button" className="btn" onSubmit={this.handleSubmitForm} >Post</button>
                 <button type="button" className="btn cancel" onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</button>
               </div>

             </form>
           </div>
        }
    }
    export default YourComponent
```

Comment: So in this scenario, we've basically moved the post logic from the backend into React. Is this common practice, and what kinds of things would we still need Express to handle?

Comment: Sorry @Mknerr, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `we've basically moved the post logic from the backend into React`. The frontend app will make a POST request to the backend in order to process something I guess. How are you handling that in your react app?

Comment: I believe it's from this line: `<form action="http://localhost:5000/api/posts" method="post" className="form-container">`